# What does an AndroidGo recommended app look like on AndroidGo Play Store?

Tags: android, performance, optimization, google-play, android-go

Trying to optimize my bicycle app to be recommended on AndroidGo. Reading documentation it was mentioned theres some kind of badge displayed when an app is optimized for the Go Version of Android but I dont see one. Even on AndriodGo apps from Google

Can someone explain what this looks like and provide a link to one of these Google-recommended AndroidGo apps so I know what im benchmarking against when were optimizing?

Thanks

[image: You can see apps have download sizes when viewed from AndroidGo but even Googles AndroidGo 'optimized' app does not show anything near it to recommend it to ppl on AndroidGo ( other than icon image )]

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the documentation about [Android Go](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/androidgo) and in [particular the development guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/androidgo/develop#play-store) for up to date details.

Comment: Thanks for the links! Definitely some new info in there - disappointed that Google did not include how they count and/or display when an app IS Go optimized though...